# Combining bold and multi-page index numbering

Tags: fonts, indexing, bold

Wish to have some multi-page Index numbering (e.g.: `\index{Text|(}` `\index{Text|)}`) appear BOLD. I tried adding `\index{Text|textbf}` but got no BOLD.

What's the trick?

Comment: Welcome Rotring! A tip: to mark code within text, you could use backticks. If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they are displayed as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "101010" on it).

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I don't understand how that relates to the question of combining the two different Index requests: One for BOLD, the other for Multi-pages. There must be a way of combining these two? Thanks again, I'm new to this.

Comment: @Rotring: Stefan was explaining how to format questions/answers on this site.

Comment: Sorry I'm ill-equipped to be posting here... just thought this would be a real simple process of merely adding a mark or two... Tried simply combining them together, but the numbers were not bold, as they are when I use |textbf for a single page... The content of my message reads as I intended on this end---is it not when you view it?

Comment: Herbert: Everything is fine with the Index and I can use both bold single page entries and regular multi-page entries. My question is that I just don't know how to combine the "command," or whatever it's called, to get bold multi-page entries (combining \index{Text|(} with |textbf somehow). Have scoured the internet & cant find it. Must be incredibly simple, though.

Comment: @Rotring: see edited answer

Comment: Herbert provided the answer. Many thanks also to Stefan & Caramdir for helping me along...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{makeidx} \makeindex
\begin{document}

Text\index{Text@\textbf{Text}|(textbf}
\newpage foo
\newpage foo
\newpage foo
\index{Text@\textbf{Text}|)textbf}
\newpage foo
\index{Text}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes! That did it, thank-you, Herbert! One other question: All my regular Index page entries are underlined as hyper-reference, but not those in bold. It doesn't matter for what I'm doing, but just curious how that works. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Example ... I have not problem with the above code and `hyperref`

Comment: I'll study what you provided some more & see what I'm doing differently. As I say, hyperref doesn't matter for my project, I'm just curious. I have been using LaTeX for several years now with no need of assistance until this. I find it to be incredibly user-friendly even though I know nothing about it and am not from a quantitative, or programing background. This is the only issue that has required me to know anything about the language, structure, or even something as simple as knowing how to properly post a question. Thanks again to you & the others for your patience, I really appreciate it.

Comment: I thought this was working, but two things-the way you have it here creates a redundant entry for the indexed word each time it's used, creating a new list, so I removed the Text@ part and it compiled & looked fine. Then after happily indexing away, I could not compile & discovered that the delimiters {} were not consistent with the parentheses marks (). Now I can't get any of it to work at all!

Comment: P.S.: I performed a Delimiter check of the entire document and only these commands (attempting bold with page range) show problems ( } incompatibility. Must be an easy way to write it so that it goes through without clogging up the compiler?

Comment: If the solution is redundant, then give an example where the index text _and_ the index pagenumber is in bold!